Flutter - Lottie animation heavily distorted and deformed
I am implementing a Lottie animation within my App.
The animation Framerate and the animation loop work fine with no troubles.
But the animation in itself is distorted, it is so deformed to the point is not recognizable anymore.
I found what could be the reason which is expressions not supported in this Github thread
but I am no animator and do not know what that could mean but it looks like is the most probable cause.
What could be the appropriate fix to this issue?
For reference here is a link to the .json of the animation I am experimenting with.
What I have tried so far

tried using premade palettes and custom palettes
tried downloading and using .json as a local asset with Lottie.asset() and using Lottie.network()
tried other animations a well, same distortion
tried tweaking the size and the fit using Boxfit

None of the those solutions worked so far.

If you have access to the original AE project, I would use the 'bake expressions to keyframes' export option so that the values are built in to the animation and not calculated during runtime, removing the expression.

Hmm, I don't, I don't even have AE on my machine!
